# is it "aite" or "akete" for "open"?

Tags: usage, て-form

I have a book and when you do the verb conjugation for "te" My book says "open" is "aite", but other websites say it's "akete". Which one is correct?

Answer (score 11):

Transitive vs. Intransitive.

[開]{あ}ける (akeru) vs. [開]{あ}く (aku)

You 開ける the door. vs. The door 開く by itself.

開ける conjugates to　開けて (akete) and 開く conjugates to 開いて (aite).

Answer (score 1):

"aite" is a form of "aku" which is an intransitive verb that means "open".

"akete" is a form of "akeru" which is a transitive verb "open".

It's a little confusing for English speakers because "open" can be used transitively OR intransitively.

> "The door opened" vs. "I opened the door"

You can also use "open" as an adjective in English!

> The library is open.

In Japanese this can be expressed with the transitive verb "aku".

> *Toshokan ga aiteiru.*

To sum up, English is confusing.